# How can you continue SQL query when found error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can you continue SQL query when found error while querying?

I want to continue a query if any error will occur. I want to get the output of a certain statement and want to see if what is the last output of the query.

How can you do it in T-SQL?

Comment: You can't continue a **query** and ignore all errors. Assuming you mean that you would want a result set with `1,2` from the following `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT CAST('X' AS INT) UNION ALL SELECT 2) T(C)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Is TRY CATCH useful in my case?

Comment: What is your case? If it is as per my earlier comment then no that won't do what you want. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MartinSmith Is TRY..CATCH useful when i want to continue a query? I've been trying the CASE..WHEN...CONTINUE but it gives me an error

Comment: When you say *query*, do you mean a *single* statement (like a single SELECT or a single INSERT or single UPDATE etc.) or a *batch* (as in *multi-statement query*)?

Comment: What is your case? What SQL do you have that you want to "continue" in case of an error? Show us a piece of code, don't leave us hanging.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a TRY-CATCH for error handling.

You can find enough documentation here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

**UPDATE:**

After a bit more research I have found that using a `GO` command will allow you to continue to your next query, and you won't have to restructure your entire code with TRY-CATCH statements. I still recommend using TRY-CATCH statements to control errors, but just use `GO` between them.

This is the link where I found the answer: [continue-executing-sql-statements-despite-errors](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4ed06985-c9c8-42a5-a621-a855634efec2/continue-executing-sql-statements-despite-errors)

Comment: This doesn't really explain how one can have the SQL query *continue* when using `TRY...CATCH`.

Comment: TRY CATCH only allows you to control error handling. Not continue.

Comment: This helped. I paired GO with the running of a 118mb script on SQLCMD -d <Databasename> -i <instancename> . turns out it was a single, annoying, little, enfuriating change one of the developers made causing one of my values to not find a foreign key :)

Comment: @Noobgrammer Glad it was useful!